# Distributed transaction already begun "ORA 02046 " when I use Link

Tags: .net, oracle, devart

I have a very big problem for me appears with a few steps when I use devart to connect to Oracle.

- Select on the following view in Oracle 
  Code:

  ```
  create or replace view Test_View as 
  select "ID","USR" 
  from Test_Table@link_DB; `
  ```
- Using LINQ CONNECT MODAL

That's all, 
When I open the page the following exception will be shown (from the first time or after a postBack)

> distributed transaction already begun "ORA 02046 "

Any help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with distributed transactions state on your Oracle database servers.

Try to rollback "in-doubt" distributed transaction as described [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/ds_txns.htm#991).

Step-by-step-guide located [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/ds_txnman.htm#6933).

Answer (score 1):

We have replied you at our forum [here](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=20249).
By the way, have you tried the solution recommended by @ThinkJet?